# Keras CategoryEncoding layer with time sequences

Tags: python, keras, encoding, one-hot-encoding

For a LSTM, I create time sequences by means of `tensorflow.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array()`. For some of the features, I would like to do one-hot encoding by means of Keras preprocessing layers.

I have the following code:

```
n_timesteps = 20
n_categorical_features = 1

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, IntegerLookup, CategoryEncoding

cat_inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_categorical_features), name = "categorical_input")
index = IntegerLookup()
index.adapt(X["br"])
encoder = CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=index.vocabulary_size(), output_mode = "one_hot")(cat_inp)
```

However, the last line gives me the error `ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "category_encoding_22" (type CategoryEncoding). When output_mode is not` 'int'`, maximum supported output rank is 2. Received output_mode one_hot and input shape (None, 20, 1), which would result in output rank 3.` The problem seems to be that CategoryEncoding does not support the shape of my input tensor (None, n_timesteps, n_categorical_features).

How can I one-hot encode the input tensor produced by `timeseries_dataset_from_array()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to use TimeDistributed layer:

```
encoder = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=index.vocabulary_size(), output_mode = "one_hot"))(cat_inp)
```

It will apply CategoryEncoding to each item in your time sequence. Please see https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/
for more information.